# how to find the type is select or input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
  <span><input type="text"></input></span>
  <span><select>
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select></span>
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
if($(demo).find(nth-child(2)).is('select'))
{
  //something
}
```

I need to check whether it is a select or input type.Kindly help me!

Comment: `$('#demo').children('nth-child(2)').is('select')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, you just need to wrap the selectors in quotes and include the required prefixes. Try this:

```
if ($('#demo').find(':nth-child(2)').is('select')) {
    console.log('its a select');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r94kkkyo/)

Comment: If it is in a span means how to check@Rory

Comment: Change `$('#demo')` to `$('#demo span')`

Answer (score 2):

Getting the element type the jQuery way:

```
var elementType = $(element).prop('tagName');
```

doing the same without jQuery

```
var elementType = document.getElementById("elementId").tagName;
```

Checking for specific element type:

```
var is_element_input = $(element).is("input"); //true or false
```

Please refer the  fiddle : "http://jsfiddle.net/r94kkkyo/2/"